# IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f07003c for fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to Fragments. I tried simple fragment example. But it throws the error. I don't know what is wrong.

```
public class NewActivity extends Activity {
    int mStackLevel = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Fragment newFragment = NewFragment
                    .newInstance(mStackLevel);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.simple_fragment, newFragment).commit();
        } else {
            mStackLevel = savedInstanceState.getInt("level");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("level", mStackLevel);
    }
    public static class NewFragment extends Fragment {
        int mNum;
        Context context;

        static NewFragment newInstance(int num) {
            NewFragment f = new NewFragment();

            // Supply num input as an argument.
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("num", num);
            f.setArguments(args);

            return f;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("num") : 1;
            context = getActivity();
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, container,
                    false);         
            return v;
        }
    }

}
```

My logcat shows:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.FragmentExample/com.example.FragmentExample.NewActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f07003c for fragment NewFragment{40ff0850 #0 id=0x7f07003c}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ft.add(R.id.simple_fragment, newFragment).commit();
```

you missed `setContentView` for your Activity. Your Fragment can not be added without a View hierarchy.

Note : Your Fragment is hosted by an activity. So you need to set the content to the activity first.

Comment: nice catch. i starred at the question few times missed at spotting the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace this method with your method

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(Your_layout_file);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Fragment newFragment = NewFragment
                    .newInstance(mStackLevel);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.simple_fragment, newFragment).commit();
        } else {
            mStackLevel = savedInstanceState.getInt("level");
        }
    }
```

you missed this line `setContentView(Your_layout_file);`

Answer (score 0):

This answer highlights a silly mistake that may occur, that arises when nesting fragments or you are converting activities to fragments.

If you are trying to replace a fragment within a fragment with the `fragmentManager` but you are **not inflating the parent fragment** that can cause an issue.

In **BaseFragment.java** `OnCreateView`:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, new DifferentFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
```

Replace `super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);` 
with inflating the correct layout for the fragment:

```
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.base_fragment, container, false);
```